# APICall response fails to parse data

Tags: java, android, api, gson, retrofit

I need to Parse data from this URL https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?apiKey=6946d0c07a1c4555a4186bfcade76398&sortBy=top&source=bbc-news , but when i make an apicall, it never enters onResponse function, but always onFailure.
Always getting an "ERROR" Toast that is in onFailure.

I have tried changing BASE_URL and Query to several different options but it doesn't help. Maybe it is a problem with my object, but I can't find the mistake.

*****UPDATE*****: I changed my Object like said in comments, but still getting onFailure function.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
OnItemClickListener{

public static final String EXTRA_TITLE="Title";
public static final String EXTRA_DESCRIPTION="Description";
public static final String EXTRA_URL="URL";


private RecyclerView recycler;
private RecyclerAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<NewsCell> newsList;
private Call<List<NewsCell>> apiCall;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    newsList=new ArrayList<>();
    setupRecycler();
    setUpApiCall();


}

private void setUpApiCall(){
 apiCall=NetworkUtils.getApiInterface().getNews(
             "6946d0c07a1c4555a4186bfcade76398","top","bbc-news");
 apiCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<NewsCell>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<NewsCell>> call, 
Response<List<NewsCell>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body().size()!=0){
                newsList.addAll(response.body());
                adapter=new 
RecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this,newsList,MainActivity.this);
                recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No results", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<NewsCell>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}

private void setupRecycler() {
    recycler=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    Intent detailIntent=new Intent(this,NewsSingle.class);
    NewsCell clickedItem=newsList.get(position);

    detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE,clickedItem.getTitle());
    detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_DESCRIPTION,clickedItem.getDescription());
    detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_URL,clickedItem.getUrlToImage());

    startActivity(detailIntent);
}

}
```

NetvorkUtils.java

```
public class NetworkUtils {
private static final String BASE_API="https://newsapi.org/v1/";
private static APIInterface apiInterface;

public static APIInterface getApiInterface(){
    if(apiInterface==null){
        Retrofit retrofit =new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_API)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        apiInterface=retrofit.create(APIInterface.class);
    }
    return apiInterface;
}
}
```

APIInterface.java

```
public interface APIInterface {
@GET("articles")
Call<List<NewsCell>> getNews(@Query("apiKey") String key, @Query("sortBy") 
String sort,@Query("source") String source);
}
```

Article.java

```
public class Article {

@SerializedName("author")
@Expose
private String author;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;
@SerializedName("urlToImage")
@Expose
private String urlToImage;
@SerializedName("publishedAt")
@Expose
private String publishedAt;

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getUrlToImage() {
    return urlToImage;
}

public void setUrlToImage(String urlToImage) {
    this.urlToImage = urlToImage;
}

public String getPublishedAt() {
    return publishedAt;
}

public void setPublishedAt(String publishedAt) {
    this.publishedAt = publishedAt;
}

}
```

NewsCell.java

```
public class NewsCell {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("source")
@Expose
private String source;
@SerializedName("sortBy")
@Expose
private String sortBy;
@SerializedName("articles")
@Expose
private List<Article> articles = null;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getSource() {
    return source;
}

public void setSource(String source) {
    this.source = source;
}

public String getSortBy() {
    return sortBy;
}

public void setSortBy(String sortBy) {
    this.sortBy = sortBy;
}

public List<Article> getArticles() {
    return articles;
}

public void setArticles(List<Article> articles) {
    this.articles = articles;
}

}
```

Comment: Did u check api in postman?

Comment: The problem is with your object. It is a Json object with fields status, source, sortBy, articles. The first three are string types and the articles field is a json array. Please closely check the response from api first.

Comment: @Athira no I didn't, I never used that. Not familiar with it, could you explain to me how to use it please.

Comment: Postman is available as a chrome plug-in. Just add postman to chrome, You give your api in field, set api type GET or POST. if post you can give parameters name and value in body section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting response like this[image]

but in your model class `NewsCell` you are parsing only `title ,description and urlToImage` .which is **inside** `articles` array

```
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("urlToImage")
@Expose
private String urlToImage;
```

So I would suggest you to copy whole your response . [goto this site](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and generate your model class properly . and paste in into your `NewsCell`

Comment: I changed my object, but I am still getting the Error Toast. Had to change some things in RecyclerAdapter too, but I think that those changes do not effect ApiCall.

Comment: in toast message also print your error `Throwable t`

Comment: This is the error that I am getting :  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: @ZvonimirPavlović  you have to change `Call<List<NewsCell>>` to `Call<NewsCell>` also

Comment: I managed to fix it. Had to make just one object of NewsCell and then make list of Aricles. Thank you very much on your help :)

Comment: @ZvonimirPavlović i'm glad i helped you